# C - How client can use/access more than one implementation?

Tags: c, coding-style, refactoring

Below(image) is the imitation approach from  `Linux/net/socket.c` source.

> **Background:**
>
> Reason to implement `List` abstraction with this approach, is to make a  **working prototype** before implementing snmp library, with same approach.
>   f
>   Inspired from `Linux/net/socket.c`, where **any one** of the protocol family implementations(like `net/ipv4/af_inet.c` or `net/unix/af_unix.c`/..) is available on invoking `socket()` interface api
>
> Client invoking `socket()` api, avails **any one** protocol family implementation based on the argument(`AF_INET` | `AF_UNIX` | `AF_XYZ`) passed to `socket()` interface api.

### [image]

In the above approach, `list.h` provides `List` interface, with code shown below,

```
/********************** list.h ********************/


#ifndef LIST_H /* Header guard */
#define LIST_H
#include"type.h"

/****************** Interface - start  ********/

 typedef struct List List;
 typedef enum {ARRAY_IMPL, LINKED_LIST_IMPL}ImplType;


 typedef int (*compareTo)(const void *, const void *);
 typedef bool (*isLess)(const void *, const void *);
 typedef bool (*isEqual)(const void *, const void *);

 List* createList(ImplType);
  void freeList(List*);
  void swim(List*, int, isLess);
  void sink(List*, int, isLess);
const  void* deleteMax(List*, isLess);
const  void* sortDeleteMax(List*);
   int getSize(List*);
const void* getItem(List*, const int);
 List* sortInsertItem(List*, const void*, compareTo);
  void insertItem(List*, const void*);
const  void* deleteItem(List*, int);
const  void* deleteLastItem(List*);
const  void* deleteFirstItem(List*);
   int lSearch(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo);
   int bSearch(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo);
  void callInsertionSort(List*, size_t, isLess);
  void callMergeSort(List*, size_t, isLess);
  void swap(List*, int, int);
/****************** Interface - end  ********/
#endif
```

---

Linking of implementation(`arrayImpl.o`/`linkListImpl.o`) to executable(`a.out`) happen at linker phase.

`virtualImplLayer.c` picks **any one** implementation handler based on the argument(`ARRAY_IMPL | LINKED_LIST_IMPL`) passed to `createList()` interface api. This implementation handler is stored in `handler` global variable, as shown below. **Rest of the interface api rely on this global variable.**

```
/*****************virtualImplLayer.c*************************/
#include "list/listHandler.h"

/*****Private symbol - start *****************/
static ListHandler * findListImplHandler(ImplType);
/*****Private symbol - end   *****************/


ListHandler *handler = NULL;
/***** User interface - start *************/
List* createList(ImplType implType){

  handler =  findListImplHandler(implType);

  if(handler != NULL){

    List *list = handler->createList();
    return list;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "createList() - No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;

}


void freeList(List *list){

    handler->freeList(list);
}


void swim(List *list, int parentIndex, isLess less){

    handler->swim(list, parentIndex, less);

}


void sink(List *list, int index, isLess less){

    handler->sink(list, index, less);
}


const void* deleteMax(List *list, isLess less){

    return handler->listDeleteMaxElement(list, less);
}


const void* sortDeleteMax(List *list){

    return handler->sortedListDeleteMaxElement(list);
}
int getSize(List *list){

    return handler->listGetSize(list);
}


const void* getItem(List *list, const int index){

    return handler->listGetItem(list, index);
}


List* sortInsertItem(List *list, const void *item, compareTo compare){

    return handler->sortedListInsertItem(list, item, compare);
}


void insertItem(List *list, const void *item){

    handler->listInsertItem(list, item);
}
const void* deleteItem(List *list, int listIndex){

    return handler->listDeleteItem(list, listIndex);
}


const void* deleteLastItem(List *list){

    return handler->listDeleteLastItem(list);
}


const void* deleteFirstItem(List *list){

    return handler->listDeleteFirstItem(list);
}


int lSearch(const void *key, List *list, size_t size, compareTo compare){

    return handler->linearSearch(key, list, size, compare);
}


int bSearch(const void *key, List *list, size_t size, compareTo compare){

    return handler->binarySearch(key, list, size, compare);
}
void callInsertionSort(List *list, size_t size, isLess less){

    handler->insertionSort(list, size, less);
}


void callMergeSort(List *list, size_t size, isLess less){

    handler->mergeSort(list, size, less);
}


void swap(List *list, int i, int j){

    handler->swap(list, i, j);
}

/***** User interface -end *************/

/*****Private symbol - start *****************/
static ListHandler * findListImplHandler(ImplType implType){

  ListHandler *implHandler = NULL;
  int handlerIndex = 0;
  while(listHandlers[handlerIndex] !=NULL){

    implHandler = listHandlers[handlerIndex];
    if( implHandler->canHandle(implType) ){
      return implHandler;
    }
    handlerIndex++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
/*****Private symbol - end *****************/
```

---

Implementations like `Linux/net/ipv4/af_inet.c`,`Linux/net/unix/af_unix.c` are linked at loading phase by overriding `_init()` run-time code in the implementation(say `af_inet.c`), as shown below,

```
static int __init inet_init(void){
  ....
  void)sock_register(&inet_family_ops);
  ....
}
```

---

Coming to the question, With given implementation in `virtualImplLayer.c`, a client program cannot expect to use/access *more than one* implementations(`arrayImpl.c`/`LinkListImpl.c`), because `handler` variable gets overridden

---

Complete working example is [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/design2Code/list) with compilng instructions given [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/design2Code/ReadMe.txt)

**Question:**

With the `ImplType` being passed only to `createList()` interface, In `virtualImplLayer.c`, How to avoid overriding of global variable `handler`, to avail multiple implementations?

Comment: By not having a global there (virtualImplLayer.c) for it at all. Have `findListImplHandler` cache the result instead for easy lookup. While working with any 1 list implementation, the lookup will be fast. When switching, it will incur a single lookup miss.

Comment: And now a nitpick, since your question is nice in my opinion. But you seriously need to work on the "Minimal" aspect of a [mcve].

Comment: @StoryTeller Updated query with details on working example

Comment: Your example wasn't short on details. Quite the opposite. If someone wants to actually understand your question, they'd need to sift through a lot of irrelevant details (yes, most of the code you've shown as well as the design notes are irrelevant).

Comment: @StoryTeller OK. If there are irrelevant details then please edit the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove the global, is by storing some type info in `List` itself.

You can for instance enforce a convention (by thinking a bit OO, as far as C facilitates it). Both `List` implementations must include as the first member the following `struct`

```
struct ListRtti {
  ListHandler *handler_;
  // Other relevent meta data you may want
};
```

So

```
struct List {
  ListRtti rtti_;

  // Implementation details
};
```

Now, you can retrieve the handler from the pointer to the object itself. Since the address of the first member is guaranteed to be the address of the entire object:

```
((ListRtti*)list)->handler_;
```

Pro:

- The handler is always a single indirection away.
- Users can mix and interchange implementations to their hearts content.

Cons:

- The meta data requires extra storage for every object allocated.
- That cast can raise eyebrows.

Comment: So, implementation details of `struct ListRtti` only should be visible to `virtualImplLayer.c`. Implementation details of `struct List`, not needed to be visible

Comment: @overexchange - Pretty much.

Comment: Does `socket()` api allow invoking `socket(AF_INET,,)` and `socket(AF_UNIX,,)` from single client using socket library?

Comment: @overexchange - [Nothing in the docs says you can't](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html)

Comment: I made the code changes [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/design2Code) accordingly and it is working. Thank you!!

Comment: @overexchange - Happy to help :)